# Androird/Eclipse : Stretching an image to fit with screen borders

Tags: android, eclipse, image, stretch

I have this 9-patch picture "Imageview3"
[image]

I want to add in my activity. I want the red arms to matchs perfecty with the borders of the screen.
But when I do SCALE:fitXy here is what I obtain
[image]
so as you can seem it doesn't work, I tried all the scales, I tried to stretch the image but it never fits.

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >


         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView2"
             android:layout_width="324dp"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"
             android:paddingTop="150dp"
             android:paddingRight="0dp"
             android:src="@drawable/diviseur" />

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView3"
             android:layout_width="407dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:scaleType="fitXY"
             android:src="@drawable/a1"
             android:visibility="visible" />

</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `android:scaleType="fitXY"` and keep `android:layout_width="match_parent"`. Try it.

Comment: I had to use "fill_parent", not satisfying either : the image centers but does not stretch well :/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your actual image doesn't have a white border around it. As in, make sure the arms are at the very end of your image.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using android:src="@drawable/diviseur",  try using android:background="@drawable/diviseur". And also consider using android:layout_weight="1" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/banner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/foo"
    />
```